# pure-ftpd symlink not working

Tags: linux, ftp, symlink, pureftpd

I've got a setup where pure-ftpd is allowing symlink.

**what works**

`/var/www/some_website/symlink_to_logs` works and resolves to `/var/log/some_website_logs/`

(this is to show that symlinks are allowed and resolved). Also, creating symlinks to other folders such as `/home/temp/` would work fine

**what doesn't work**

`/var/www/some_website/symlink_to_backups` that resolves to `/var/log/some_website_backups/`

that gives a `Permission denied` error when browsing with a FTP client (Filezilla).

permissions are set to be at least r (as in r-wr-wr--) to `/var` , `/var/log` and `/var/log/some_website_backups` so why the error?

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as i'm currently stuck.

**edit** : the error shows up when browsing using a FTP client (Filezilla)

**edit 2** : i tried mounting the folder with `mount --bind` in the FTP dir (so it'd show up as another directory) and i still get `Permission denied`.

**edit 3** :   `namei -m symlink_to_backups`

```
      f: symlink_to_backups
         lrwxrwxrwx symlink_to_backups-> /var/log/some_website_backups
            drwxr-xr-x /
            drwxr-xr-x var
            drwxr-xr-- log
            drw-rw-r-- some_website_backups
```

Comment: What does the **log** say ?

Comment: `[ERROR] Can't open symlink_to_backups: Permission denied` is the only relevant syslog entry to be found when adding `yes` to `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/VerboseLog`

Comment: So what does `namei -m /var/log/some-website/symlink_to_backups` say ?

Comment: added extra info to the question (edit 3)

Comment: also, `namei symlink_to_logs` produces similar output to `namei symlink_to_backups`

Comment: ...that's not what I asked for. Which should be obvious, since it doesn't show permissions

Comment: oh, will ammend.. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drw-rw-r-- some_website_backups
```

As you can see, the leaf directory does not have execute permissions - for ***anybody***.

Comment: that fixed it (adding +x to leafs). can you please explain why directory listing needs execute rights ?

Comment: Because the execute bit for a directory means "you may descend here". Unless the program trying to get access knows the **exact** filename inside that directory, all operations will fail, since it cannot enter it to retrieve a list of files.

Comment: @adaptr actually, that's a little backwards.  If you have `r` but not `x` on a directory, you can read the directory to get the list of files, but can't open any of them because you aren't allowed to *be in* the directory.  If you have `x` but not `r`, you can't get a list of files, but you can open a file if you know its name.  It's like a house: `r` means the curtains are open and you can look through the window and see what books are on the shelf, but without `x` the doors are locked and you can't get in to read any.